# How do I make the data show up formatted on my localhost?

Tags: javascript, formatting, localhost, google-sheets-api

[image: my localhost][image: youtube video localhost]

I am trying to use the google sheets API and I'm following along with a YouTube video. Why does the data show up so orderly on his computer and so unformatted on mine? How can I change it?

I looked into the settings and I Googled it, but I probably don't know the right terms to get the results I'm looking for.

Comment: If you output the API response to console and open Chrome Developer console, the output will be formatted.

Comment: Also can you add the link to the youtube video you're following? It's hard to tell from the second image if the formatted JSON is is from an IDE or developer console.

Comment: Check the response headers and see the content type is `application/json`. Also, people can probably tell what browser you're using, but you should be explicit about it.